# Calculating the derivatives in a linear layer in NN

Tags: vector-analysis, neural-networks, derivations

There is the following puzzle that stems from Neural networks:

I have a matrix $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}\mathbf{W}^{T} + \mathbf{B}$ where $\mathbf{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^{S \times N}$, $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{S \times N}$, $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{S \times M}$ and $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times M}$,

Finally, since the whole linear operator (usually passes through an activation layer that works element-wise) $L = h(\mathbf{Y})$

I would like to calculate the $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{W}}$. We can first calculate the result using "index notation":

$$ \left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{W}} \right]_{ij} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial {W}_{ij}} = \sum_{m}^{S} \sum_{n}^{N} \frac{\partial L}{\partial Y_{mn}} \frac{\partial Y_{mn}}{\partial W_{ij}} = \sum_{m}^{S} \sum_{n}^{N} \frac{\partial L}{\partial Y_{mn}} \frac{\partial(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{W}^{T} + \mathbf{B})}{\partial W_{ij}} \  \ \ \  [1]$$.

Note that we can write the expression $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{W}^{T} = \sum_p X_{mp}W_{np}$ and we can ignore $\mathbf{B}$ since it will die later during the differentiation.

So focusing on the second fraction and using Kronecker deltas we do have:

$$\frac{\partial(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{W}^{T})_{mn}}{\partial W_{ij}} = \frac{\partial(\sum_p X_{mp}W_{np})}{\partial W_{ij}}  = \sum_{p} X_{mp}\delta_{in}\delta_{pj} = X_{mj}\delta_{in}$$

Now, back to Equation (1):

$$ \left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{W}} \right]_{ij} = \sum_{m}^{S} \sum_{n}^{N} \frac{\partial L}{\partial Y_{mn}} \frac{\partial(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{W}^{T} + \mathbf{B})}{\partial W_{ij}} = \sum_{m}^{S} \sum_{n}^{N} \frac{\partial L}{\partial Y_{mn}} X_{mj}\delta_{in} = \sum_{m}^{S} \frac{\partial L}{\partial Y_{mi}} X_{mj} = \left[(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{Y}})^{T} \mathbf{X} \right]_{ij}$$

Back to matrix notation, we do have:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{W}} = (\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{Y}})^{T} \mathbf{X}$$

Firstly, is my logic correct? My main question is how can I motivate the conclusion from index to matrix notation?

Secondly is there a difference between: $$(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{Y}})^{T} \mathbf{X}$$ and  $$\mathbf{X}^{T}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{Y}})$$

Finally, how exactly can I motivate that $ \frac{\partial \mathbf{Y}}{\partial \mathbf{W}}$, did not lead to a 4d tensor and was just a matrix at the end?

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\L{{\cal L}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$The formula which you derived is correct.
Here is another way to calculate it...

Assume that the gradient of a scalar cost function $\L$ with respect to the matrix $Y$ is known.

Expand the  *differential* of $\L\,$ and change the independent variable from $\,Y\to W$
$$\eqalign{
Y &= XW^T + B \qiq &dY = X\:dW^T \\
G &= \grad{\L}{Y} &\{{\rm known\ gradient}\} \\
d\L &= G:dY  &\{{\rm differential}\} \\
 &= G:\LR{X\,dW^T} \\
 &= G^T:\LR{dW\,X^T} \\
 &= \LR{G^TX}:dW \\
\grad{\L}{W}
 &= {G^TX} &\{{\rm new\ gradient}\}  \\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the Frobenius product, which is a concise
notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{AB}:C &= A:\LR{CB^T} \;=\; B:\LR{A^TC} \\
}$$
The advantage of using differentials is to avoid the need for any awkward fourth-order tensors.

### Update

I misread the question. Here is the derivation for the tensor-valued gradient.

Define the following tensors
$$\eqalign{
\def\d{\delta}  \def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\H{{\large\cal H}} \def\F{{\cal F}}
&\F_{ijkl} = \d_{il}\,\d_{jk} \\
&\H_{ij\,kl\,mn} = \begin{cases}
\o \qquad {\rm if}\;i=k=m\;\;{\rm and}\;\;j=l=n \\
0 \qquad {\rm otherwise}
\end{cases}
}$$
and the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
L = h(Y), \qquad L' = h'(Y) \\
}$$
where $h'$ is the ordinary (scalar) derivative of the $h$ function and is applied elementwise.

Expand the differential of the matrix-valued function
and change $Y\to W$ once again
$$\eqalign{
dL
 &= L'\odot dY \\
 &= L':\H:dY \qquad\qiq \grad LY = L':\H \\
 &= L':\H:\LR{X\,dW^T} \\
 &= L':\H:\LR{X\cdot\F}:dW \\
\grad LW &= L':\H:\LR{X\cdot\F} \\
\\
\grad{L_{kl}}{W_{pq}}
 &= L'_{ij}\:\H_{ijklmn}\:{X_{ms}\F_{snpq}} \\
 &= h'(Y_{ij})\;\H_{ijklmn}\:{X_{mq}\,\d_{np}} \\
}$$
In the above,
$(\cdot)$ is the single-contraction product,
$(:)$ is the double-contraction product,
$(\odot)$ is the elementwise/Hadamard product,
and the index expression employs the [Einstein summation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EinsteinSummation.html) convention.

$\sf NB\!:\:$ The Hadamard tensor $\H$ is a sixth-order tensor defined such that
$$ A\odot B = A:\H:B \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad $$
$\qquad$ for any two matrices $\{A,B\}$ which have identical dimensions.

Comment: Are the two derivations a the end the same thing? $G^{T}X$ with $X^{T}G$?
To be honest I have lost you in the solution since I am not that familiar with the Frobenius form.

Comment: Not sure how exactly I am avoiding the awkward 4d tensor in that case!

Comment: Depending on your preferred [layout convention](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions) it can be written as either $\,G^TX\,$ or $\,X^TG.\;$

Comment: $\large\frac{\partial Y}{\partial W}$ is a fourth-order tensor which is **required** by the chain rule, does not appear in the differential method.

Comment: Ok that makes sense for the layout. But for the tensor thingy, I am curious how exactly after the application of the chain rule the 4d tensor is neutralized? The solution implies that the result is a matrix and not a tensor.

Is there a way to explain that result using index notation? Is it that I have indeed a 4d tensor as a solution that parts of it is filled with zeros (the third and fourth rank of it)?

Comment: Oops!  My derivation is for a scalar-valued cost function $\cal L$ rather than a matrix-valued activation function $L=h(Y)$.  I suspect that you are trying to calculate the tensor $\large\frac{\partial L}{\partial W}$ in a misguided attempt to apply the chain rule in a larger context, and you can avoid the need for this tensor by using differentials.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on this? I know ofc that $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial W}$$ should be a matrix and not a 4d matric since $L$ is a scalar. But how exactly I can motivate that the 4d is neutralized during the chain rule?

Comment: I've updated the post with the tensor result.  As you can see, it's not very pretty. How will you use it? I suspect that you will simply plug it into the chain rule to evaluate the gradient of a _scalar_ cost function.